# Simple Google Analytics for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am using a simple **Google Analytics** code. When I look the real-time users on Google Analytics, I can see "1 active user now". There is no problem, but I am suspicious that this code will give wrong results on Google Analytics because When I look their guides, their implementations is different. Can this code give wrong result on Google Analytics?
My Code:

Declaration in MainActivity

```
public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
public static Tracker tracker;
```

Implementation in onCreate

```
analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
tracker = analytics.newTracker(unitid);
tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
```

No more code, just 6 lines. 
If there is no problem for this code, why their guide is complex?

**Note:** There is no problem now, but I am suspicious about future.

Answer (score 0):

This is, indeed, close to the simplest implementation possible.

The problems with it, however, is that:

- GA library has hardcoded triggers that are qualified to be "screenviews". While it may be sufficient for very simple apps, it poorly handles layered views logic that is commonly used in more complex apps.
- GA library has to send screen identifiers. And there's little to none of what it can use for that. So what it does is it tries to pull class names as identifiers for screen names when no explicit name is set (which is the case in automated tracking). This results in the data being hard to read.

Personally I've never seen auto activity tracking being used in production. Maybe it makes sense to be used by the developers to improve exceptions logging in Firebase, but the data is way too inconsistent and hard to decode to be flexibly use for business reporting.

You achieve a lot better tracking quality when you set each screenname explicitly. That is the best practice.